# Has anyone checked out Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Has anyone checked out a copy of Drupal 7 yet? What do people think?

I'm pretty excited about the PDO and all of the designers I work with a very excited about the new admin interface/structure.

Do we have any Drupal core developers here on Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks good, and the API is now frozen so module developers can get going before the final release.

A lot of the strength of Drupal comes from the modules and until they are on D7 it won't have a huge amount of benefit over D6.

The architectural changes are good and the api changes generally seem to be a step in the right direction. Personal favourite is RDF in core.

[Eaton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19411/eaton) is still the top Drupal answerer on SO, and has done a lot of work on Drupal

[Greggles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/56791/greggles) has dabbled in SO and is part of the Drupal security team

Comment: You bet. It's a major disappointment when you're a newbie to a CMS, see a discussion about a module that EXACTLY fits your needs, jump up and down in joy and do a quick Google search and - finally when you're there at the module page, it is probably still in Alpha 1 for D7 or worse yet not at all ported, despite "promising to release on the day of D7 launch".

I still like Drupal though. It's an abusive relationship. :(

Answer (score 2):

I finally got around to signing up on SO, and I'm a core contributor. I'm obviously biased, but I think Drupal 7 is even more of an improvement over D6 than D6 was over D5. The easiest way to give it a spin is to sign up for a [Drupal Gardens](http://www.drupalgardens.com) account. It'll take a little while to get an invite though.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal Gardens is now in public beta; it is free, and you can export your site at any time.  Check out the [FAQ if you know Drupal](http://www.drupalgardens.com/content/how-do-drupal-7-and-drupal-gardens-differ).